# Why LESS is inserting a space between the selector and its pseudo class?

Tags: less

Basically I have the following Less for styling a table and I'm making use of pseudo classes to manage the column widths.

```
   .Inbound th {
        &:nth-child(-n+3),:nth-child(5),:nth-child(8){
            width: 10%;
        }
        &:nth-child(4) {
            width: 20%;
        }
        &:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+7) {
            width: 5%;
        }
    }
```

This is resulting in:

```
.Inbound th:nth-child(-n+3),
.Inbound th :nth-child(5),
.Inbound th :nth-child(8) {
  width: 10%;
}
.Inbound th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 20%;
}
.Inbound th:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(-n+7) {
  width: 5%;
}
```

Which is invalid, note the space on lines 2 & 3 after the **th** selector and prior to the **nth-child** pseudo class.

If itʼs not supposed to do this then I've found a bug in LESS.

If this is correct behavior, which is not what want, can someone point me in the direction of what I should be doing?

I have already tried the following:

- Putting all the nth-child pseudo classes on separate lines.
- Left aligning the "," & ":nth-child" pseudo classes to the far left.

Neither of which had any affect.

If itʼs of any interest Iʼm using WinLess to pre-process the Less for me and itʼs running 2.1.2 of LESS.js for parsing.

Answer (score 2):

It is doing exactly what you are telling it. There are three things that you are saying need to be under `.Inbound th`; first of them is `&:nth-child(-n+3)`, the second one is `:nth-child(5)`, the third one `:nth-child(8)`. `&` is the magic that pastes the superselector into the superselector instead of making it a descendant selector by joining the two using a space, and only the first one has it. Less is not trying to be smart and figure out what is a pseudoselector and what isn't. This allows you to do some neat tricks like this, where the subselector is not a pseudoselector at all:

```
.foo {
  &--bar { // turns into `.foo--bar`
```

Or even this (but please don't ever use this insanity):

```
t {
  &able { color: black } // turns into `table`
  &d { color: pink }     // turns into `th`
  &h { color: grey }     // turns into `td`
  sec&ion { color: white } // turns into `section`
}
```

What you want is likely

```
.Inbound th {
  &:nth-child(-n+3), &:nth-child(5), &:nth-child(8) {
    ...
```

Comment: I'll give it a go. Hereʼs hoping. Worked! Youʼre a saint!